# how to add a column with repeated string in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query in postgresql to get an ID of a table:

```
ID
A1
A2
A3
```

Now I want to add an extra column 'reason' to the above table:

```
ID   reason
A1   reason1
A2   reason1
A3   reason1
```

Basically, the question is how to add a column with repeated string 'reason1' in to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
select id, 'reason1' as reason
from your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a constant value in the table, you can add a generated column:

```
alter table t add reason varchar(255) generated always as ('reason') stored;
```

You can also add a column into the table with a default value:

```
alter table t add reason varchar(255) default 'reason1';
```